# install python package locally with pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-python-package-without-publishing-e2d36c4686cd) using pip to install a python package locally.

My structure looks like this:

```
bacnet-restful/
    example-node-red-flows/
    flask_version/
    images/
    swagger_json/
    scanning_scripts/
    modulepkg/
              __init__.py
              aioapp.py
              bacnet_actions.py
              models.py
              views.py
    .gitignore.txt
    LICENSE
    README
    requirements.txt
    runtime.txt
    setup.py
```

Per the tutorial in the `bacnet-restful` directory when I run `pip install wheel` I get this error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (0.37.0)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

Also on Windows. Python version is 3.9.6

This is my `setup.py`

```
import setuptools
 
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
 
setuptools.setup(
    name="bacnet-restful",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="author newb",
    author_email="newb.newb@gmail.com",
    description="restful BACnet App",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8',
)
```

***EDIT***

```
PS C:\Desktop\bacnet-restful> pip install bacnet-restul
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bacnet-restul (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bacnet-restul
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

***EDIT 2***

I got some [tips here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/distutils/setupscript.html#) for python 3.9 on how the `setup.py` should look which worked to install the package:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='bacnet-restful',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
      author='author newb',
      author_email='newb.newb@mail.com',
      url='https://www.python.org/',
      py_modules=['aiohttp', 'BAC0', 'aiohttp_pydantic'],
     )
```

Comment: you can use visual studio code to install them

Comment: Its not the an error. Its saying you already have wheel installed.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, so instead of `pip install wheel` I need to change the name of wheel to the name of the package I want to install named bacnet-restful. So I need to run `pip install bacnet-restul` ...?

Comment: Any chance you could comment on the EDIT I made?

Comment: I dont know exactly, whether all the steps were followed or not. But I can say first just create a virtualenv with let'say python 3.9 then activate it using source command. Then just install wheel using pip install wheel. Then do `pip install .` You by this command your current package will be installed in the virtualenv

Comment: @AnandTripathi if you posted an answer Ill hit the green check box. That worked `pip install wheel` then run `pip install .` Ill also post an EDIT 2 for changes I made to my `setup.py`

Comment: Haha thanks ;). Did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following thing inside your virtualenv.

```
pip install wheel
pip install .
```